# Windows 8 Grid Template JS App, CSS manipulations dont show on all selected items in groupedItems view

Tags: javascript, css, caching, windows-8, winjs

I'm using the Win8 Grid View Template to display infos from a news site. In the lower menu bar i have implemented a function wich shuts off the titles, so that only the pictures are still visible.

This function is in a "global.js" file which is included in the "default.html" so it's available everywhere and it looks like this:

```
//function to turn titles off and on
function titleToggle() {
    var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("item-overlay");
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        if (Global.titlesAreOn) {
            titles[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            titles[i].style.display = "";
        }
    }  
    Global.titlesAreOn = !Global.titlesAreOn;
};
```

So when i call this function from the menu bar it works for the first items, but when i scroll the end of the groupedItems view (hubview) the titles are still there. When i then scroll back to the beginning the titles are there again too.

I'm also calling the titleToggle function from the `ready()` function of the "groupedItems.js" to check whether or not to display the titles depending on a global variable.  When i do that (whenever i come back to the hubpage) it works all the way, just as expected.

```
ui.Pages.define("/pages/groupedItems/groupedItems.html", {        
        navigateToGroup: function (key) {
            nav.navigate("/pages/groupDetail/groupDetail.html", { groupKey: key });
        }, 

        ready: function (element, options) {

            appbar.winControl.disabled = false;
            appbar.winControl.hideCommands(["fontSizeBt"]);      
            appbar.winControl.showCommands(["titleToggle"]);

            if (Global.titlesAreOn == false) {
                Global.titlesAreOn = true;
                Global.titleToggle();
            }
```

I made a short video to show the problem, because its kinda hard to explain --> http://youtu.be/h4FpQf1fRBY I hope you get the idea?

Why does it work when i call it from the ready() function?
Does anyone have an idea? Is it some kind of automatic item caching in order to have better performance? And how could this be solved?

Greets and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, here is why this might be happening - WinJS is using single page navigation for the app experience. This means that when you navigate to a new page, actually you don't. Instead the content is removed from the page and the new content is loaded in the same page. It is possible that at the moment you press the button not all elements have been loaded in the DOM and therefore they cannot be manipulated by your function. This is why when you call it from the ready() function it works - all contents are loaded in the DOM. It is generally better to do things in the ready() function.

About the behavior when you slide back left and the items are again reloaded with titles - for some reason the listView items are reloading. Maybe you are using live data from the news site and they are refreshing with the listView control's template again. I cannot know, but it doesn't matter. Hiding the elements is not the best approach I think. It is better to have two templates - one with a title element and one without. The button click handler should get the listView controls(they have to be loaded) and change their templates.

```
ready: function (element, options) {
     var button = document.getElementById('btn');
     button.addEventListener("click", btnClickHandler);
}
```

And the handler:

```
function btnClickHandler(e) {
    var listView = document.getElementById("listView").winControl;
    var template2 = document.getElementById("template2");
    listView.itemTemplate = template2;
};
```